# How to subset one row in dask.dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, subset, dask

I am trying to select only one row from a dask.dataframe by using command `x.loc[0].compute()`. It returns 4 rows with all having `index=0`. I tried `reset_index`, but there will still be 4 rows having `index=0` after resetting. (I think I did reset correctly because I did `reset_index(drop=False)` and I could see the original index in the new column).

I read `dask.dataframe` document and it says something along the line that there might be more than one rows with `index=0` due to how dask structuring the chunk data.

So, if I really want only one row by using `index=0` for subsetting, how can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**
Probably, your problem comes from `reset_index`. This issue is explained at the end of the answer. Earlier part of the text is just how to solve it.

For example, there is the following dask DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
 
 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'col_2': list('abcdefg')}, 
                  index=pd.Index([0,0,1,2,3,4,5]))
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
df.compute()
Out[1]: 
   col_1 col_2
0      1     a
0      2     b
1      3     c
2      4     d
3      5     e
4      6     f
5      7     g
```

it has a numerical index with repeated `0` values. As `loc` is a

> Purely label-location based indexer for selection by label

- it selects both `0`-labeled values, if you'll do a

```
df.loc[0].compute()
Out[]: 
   col_1 col_2
0      1     a
0      2     b
```

- you'll get all the rows with `0`-s (or another specified label).

In `pandas` there is a `pd.DataFrame.iloc` which helps us to select a row by it's numerical index. Unfortunately, in dask you can't do so, because the `iloc` is

> Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position.
>
> Only indexing the column positions is supported. Trying to select row positions will raise a ValueError.

To beat this problem, you can do some indexing tricks:

```
df.compute()
Out[2]: 
   index  col_1 col_2
x                    
0      0      1     a
1      0      2     b
2      1      3     c
3      2      4     d
4      3      5     e
5      4      6     f
6      5      7     g
```

- now, there's new index ranged from `0` to the length of the data frame - `1`.

It's possible to slice it with the `loc` and do the following (I suppose that select `0` label via `loc` means "select first row"):

```
df.loc[0].compute()
Out[3]: 
   index  col_1 col_2
x                    
0      0      1     a
```

**About multiplicated 0 index label**
If you need original index, it's still here an it could be accessed through the

```
df.loc[:, 'index'].compute()
Out[4]: 
x
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
```

I guess, you get such a duplication from `reset_index()` or so, because it genretates new 0-started index for each partition, for example, for this table of 2 partitions:

```
df.reset_index().compute()
Out[5]: 
   index  col_1 col_2
0      0      1     a
1      0      2     b
2      1      3     c
3      2      4     d
0      3      5     e
1      4      6     f
2      5      7     g
```